# Disable button on ajax submit

Tags: ajax

I have the following JS and HTML code and I want to disable the button when ajax request is submitting so the user wont be able to double click and disturb the process.

```
function doReshare(_intPostId) {
if(typeof cLogin === 'undefined')
    var cLogin = checkLogin();
if(cLogin!=true)
    return;
var date = new Date();
var mainId = _intPostId;
var type = 1;
var active = 0;
var postFinded = 0;
jQuery(".reshare_" + _intPostId).each(function() {
    postFinded = 1;
    objElement = jQuery(this);
    if(objElement.hasClass('sm2_playing') || objElement.hasClass('sm2_paused')) {
        // track is active
        active = 1;
    }
    if(objElement.hasClass('is_album')) {
        mainId = objElement.closest('div.playlist-box').attr('id').replace('album_', '');
        // mainId = objElement.data('mainid');
    }
    var intLikesCurrentCount = parseInt(objElement.find(".likes_count").first().text(), 10);
    if(!objElement.find(".refeed_fct").hasClass("active")) {
        if(active)
            jQuery('.player-icons.dorepost').addClass('active');
        objElement.find(".refeed_fct").addClass("active");
        //objElement.find(".likes_count").html("<i class=\"fa fa-heart-o\"></i> " + (intLikesCurrentCount + 1));
    } else {
        objElement.find(".refeed_fct").removeClass("active");
        if(active)
            jQuery('.player-icons.dorepost').removeClass('active');
        type = 0;
        //objElement.find(".likes_count").html("<i class=\"fa fa-heart-o\"></i> " + (intLikesCurrentCount - 1));
    }
});
if(!postFinded) {
    if(!jQuery(".player-icons.dorepost").hasClass("active")) {
        jQuery('.player-icons.dorepost').addClass('active');
    } else {
        jQuery('.player-icons.dorepost').removeClass('active');
    }
} 
jQuery("#vowave").append('<img width="1" height="1" src="/reshare/' + mainId + '/' + type + '?time=' +  date.getTime() + '" />');
```

}

and the html

```
<span class="refeed_fct" onclick="doReshare(10309)">
<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> <div class="inline hidden-mobile">Repost</div>
</span>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should set the objElement's onclick listener to an empty function

Comment: just add `element.onclick = function(){}`

Comment: Can you define the onclick for the span dynamically. And also give the span an id so you can specify the onclick without compatibility issues